# How to make file system on DVD

Tags: filesystems, dvd

I ran the below command to check file system on a few DVDs.

```
sudo file -s /dev/sr0
```

The DVDs which were working had responded properly to this command. But the DVDs which were not getting burnt (by Brasero disc burner etc) showed the below error.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Downloads$ sudo file -s /dev/sr0
/dev/sr0: ERROR: cannot read `/dev/sr0' (Input/output error)
```

So, I feel the problem is with the DVDs or the file system of the DVDs.

Now is there any method (like mkfs on other medias) to make file system for those DVDs?

Comment: Considering your latest questions, take also a look at the [genisoimage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/genisoimage) package on Ubuntu. In it you'll find `mkisofs`, which is basically what is underneath `growisofs` that someone mentioned in one of your Q. What it allows that the latter doesn't is outputting to an ISO file instead of directly to the device, like so `mkisofs -o imagefile.iso /path/to/tree`. Don't know that you can append to imitate RW behavior, but might help in your testing. If you could slowly build your iso then burn it when it's "full" for ex.

Answer (score 0):

First off, an I/O error indicates that there's a physical problem with the DVD. It cannot be physically read, much less have its filesystem detected.

But, to answer your question, there is no such generalized tool for DVDs or CDs. This is due to the fact that DVDs and CDs can only be written to once. Imagine what would happen if you tried to write the filesystem and files in separate steps - you'd be able to create an empty filesystem, but you wouldn't be able to modify it to include any files! Therefore, the filesystem needs to be written at the same time as the files it contains, which requires specialized tools written for DVDs and CDs.

Comment: Small nitpick but you can write multiple data tracks to a multisession disk and "add to" the filesystem over time.

Comment: @casey yeah, I almost out "_almost all_ DVDs and CDs are read only" but I didn't know enough about them. you're welcome to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're going at this in the wrong way. Blank DVDs don't have a filesystem so of course, they cannot be read. The ones that work are the ones you have already burned something on so they have a valid filesystem and the `file` command recognizes it.